# MySql statement prepare "not sticking"

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm attempting to use a prepared statement, and while the MySqlCommand executes just fine, the execution time is abysmal.  I had it write the result of cmd.IsPrepared to the console, and sure enough, it is false.  Here is where I setup the MySqlCommand:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO dict (pre, dist, dict.char, score) VALUES(@pre, @dist, @char, @score) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = score + @score";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@pre", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 32);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dist", MySqlDbType.Int32);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@char", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@score", MySqlDbType.Double);
cmd.Prepare();
```

I've also tried executing the Prepare() before adding parameters with the same result.

I then have a loop of code that does some computation and sets variables like so:

```
cmd.Parameters[3].Value = score;
```

...and does nothing else to the command until it comes time to run:

```
Console.WriteLine(cmd.IsPrepared);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The result to the console is always false.  This is all done within a basic transaction, but that doesn't seem like it should mess things up.  I do open the transaction before I setup the MySqlCommand, though.

Any ideas as to where this is going wrong?

edit: I replicated the code in java, and the prepared statements work fine in it.  So it's not a problem with my database server itself, it is specifically a problem in .net.  Surely the .net/connector isn't broken for everyone, so what could possibly be the deal here?

And it definitely isn't prepared and simply not setting that bool value, the running time in .net for some test input is so long I don't have the patience to wait it out, but in java the same input runs in ~3 minutes.  Both use basically the same code.

Here's a simple test I did in .net, so you can see the full code of what I'm trying (I removed the UID and password from the connection string, but in the normal code they are there, a connection is established, and the statement enters data into the database):

```
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=rb;UID=;PASSWORD=;"))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO test (test.test) VALUES(?asdf)";
                cmd.Prepare(); //doesn't work

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?asdf", 1);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I'm using MySql.Data.dll version 6.4.4.0 with a runtime version of v4.0.30319 in c# 2010.  I'm also including MySql.Data.MySqlClient for the above example code.

Comment: is the connection open before you create the command ? and does it stay open till you execute the command ? Do you use connection pooling ?

Comment: The connection is open and all data enters the database correctly.. just too slowly.  No idea on connection pooling, this is a private DB and this program is the only connection to it, if that possibly answers the question.

Comment: connection pooling is something part of your ADO.NET provider... which one are you using ?

Comment: never used that... sorry - perhaps someone else can help...

Comment: @user173342 how long does it take if you execute it directly from basic SQL tools? My point is: is it any slower? Are you just seeing the limit of the database performance?

Comment: @MarcGravell Well, I don't have the data actually formatted and ready to go, so I wouldn't know.  But there is assuredly a performance loss if the statement isn't prepared, it's reparsing the SQL every single time it executes.  For comparison, I was using SQLite yesterday and it ran ~10x faster than this.  I'm really stumped and this is insanely frustrating.  I've tried using all sorts of different, simple queries, different formatting, etc.. No statement is _ever_ prepared even right after the Prepare() call.  My code is just like examples I see for this on the internet...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# + MySQL prepared statement w/ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459755/c-sharp-mysql-prepared-statement-w-on-duplicate-key-update-problems)

Comment: @ChrisLively It isn't, he fixed his problem by removing single quotes, and his problem appears to have come from a malformed query.  My query is valid and I can create a prepared statement version of it in a mysql client, and it works fine.  The query also works fine in the java replication of my .net code, and it is able to prepare that statement properly in java as well.

Comment: Interesting. I've been running code using this same connector for a while and never noticed that Prepare() wasn't actually doing anything. But you're right, IsPrepared is still false after the call. I'm not having any performance issues though. Are you sure it's not something else causing them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a using on the MySqlCommand object, at least in your second example.  To get any benefit of prepared statements, you would need to not dispose of the connection and command objects.  You also will want to call prepare after setting CommandText and before setting any parameters.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

Also prepared statement parameters in MySQL aren't named, they're specified based on order.  The CommandText should just contain question marks where the parameters are, and the parameter objects need to be added in exactly that order.

Comment: That link confirms that named parameters are supported, a la cmd.Parameters.Add("?number", 1)

Answer (score 2):

Preparing an SQL statement that is going to be executed only once would not bring any performance benefit, so I'll assume you are executing it multiple times:

- Ensure you are reusing the **same `MySqlCommand` object** while repeatedly calling `ExecuteNonQuery`. Be careful how you use `using` - you don't want to dispose the `MySqlCommand` object too early.
- Only assign new parameter values before each new execution - don't change the statement text or add/remove parameters.
- You'll also possibly need to keep the `MySqlConnection` alive during all that time. Be careful about `using` here as well.

BTW, some ADO.NET providers ignore `Prepare` method altogether and "prepare" the statement only on the first execution (ODP.NET does that, not sure about MySQL). If you did everything correctly, this should have no impact on performance whatsoever...

Answer (score 1):

Try running the prepare before adding your parameters.

Comment: I have, it doesn't matter.  I have also changed how the parameters are represented ("@pre", "?pre", even "?") and written new and very simplistic queries to insert a single int into a simple test table.  Nothing ever prepares.

Answer (score 1):

I came here from this:

[MySqlCommand Prepare() never sets IsPrepared to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694783/mysqlcommand-prepare-never-sets-isprepared-to-true)

This might be your problem -- your connection string for .net needs to have the "Ignore Prepare" option set to false.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Sigh.  That poster read the source code.  It seems that many others do not have this issue (perhaps they already know about the connection string option?).   I cannot explain why it isn't in the documentation for 'prepare', or why it is turned off by default..  A link to a discussion:

http://grokbase.com/p/mysql/dotnet/0721kvem8t/prepared-statements

Too bad this didn't fix my problem -- just thought you'd like to know.  It *did* end up allowing 'prepare' to execute and turn on the IsPrepared flag.