# MySqlCommand Prepare() never sets IsPrepared to true

Tags: c#, mysql

Here's the issue: no matter what I seem to do, I can't get a MySqlCommand to actually prepare. I've tried copy/pasting the example code from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html with very slight modifications, but that does not actually work either.

I scoured Google to try and find a solution, but the closest thing that came up was: [MySql statement prepare "not sticking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866905/mysql-statement-prepare-not-sticking) which did not actually answer the question.

Here's my table setup for this test:

```
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`test_prepared_query` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `value` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

Test code in C#

```
public void TestPrepareQuery()
{
    connString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connString.Server = "localhost";
    connString.Database = "test";
    connString.UserID = "someuserid";
    connString.Password = "somepassword";

    bool isprepared;

    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString.ToString()))
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO test_prepared_query VALUES (@id, @value)", conn);
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        cmd.Prepare();
        isprepared = cmd.IsPrepared; // isprepared is false here

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", 0);

        cmd.Prepare();
        isprepared = cmd.IsPrepared; // isprepared is still false

        // this is 1 -- the query succeeds
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
            cmd.Parameters["@value"].Value = i;

            // this is 1 -- the query succeeds
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it does successfully put rows in the table, but stepping through the program reviews that the state of cmd.IsPrepared is always false. Does anyone know why this could be happening? This source code is essentially identical to the example code, with only modifications to the table name as well as real connection strings.

Edit:
I've tried variables with ?name format, and that does not work either. I've also tried only having one cmd.Prepare() method call at a time in the tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually pulled up the source code for MySql Connector / .NET and discovered that if MySqlCommand.Connection.Settings.IgnorePrepare = true (which is the default!), then calling Prepare is a no op.

The way to fix this is to explicitly set IgnorePrepare to false in the connection string. This can be done rather easily with a MySqlConnectionStringBuilder using the following code snippet:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
// .. set up the rest of your connection
connBuilder.IgnorePrepare = false;

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Cool, I had this problem a while back and never figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Glad it helped someone else. I couldn't believe how tricky this was to discover as I suspect it affects most people using prepared statements for the first time.

Comment: You answer is still saving headaches worldwide.. Wasted about 3 hours on this yesterday!

Comment: Thanks from me too! -- I wish I knew more about the why's though.  Seems like a foolish feature to turn off by default.  And it seems to me the manual for prepare should describe this -- I wouldn't have looked through the source!  I did find it later in the connection string manual.